# Is there a Rails gem or plugin to get a list of image URLs on a page, given the page's URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rubygems

Is there a Rails gem or plugin to get a list of image URLs on a page, given the page's URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem to parse the page and then get the `src` attribute of all `img` tags that appear in the document:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
irb(main):002:0> require 'nokogiri'
irb(main):003:0> require 'open-uri'
irb(main):004:0> doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741550"))
irb(main):006:0> doc.css('img').collect {|elem| elem[:src] }
=> ["http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0543907746be29497b873de97957d3ab?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
    "/posts/4741550/ivc/9291",
    "http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif"]
```

Comment: this is a great solution; but it is very slow. is there anything i can do to optimize this to be faster?